# Mounting multiple home directories, for multiple users, to multiple partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, fstab, home-directory

So my family computer had a bad case of everyone using windows and it's slow AF, when there's a perfectly good ubuntu installed on the SSD...

So I switched over to it, updated to JJ, got everything set up with a user for my wife and my oldest son. Now I have the 2 TB HDD with a crappy old install of ubuntu(just saved because some old pictures I wanted to keep,lol) and that dumb windows, freshly updated to 11 and crappy as all get outside. Seriously, who digs that junk?

Anyway, now I partition the 2 TB so I have 1000GB and the wife and son each have 400 and something GB, the whole file system is on the SSD. I get these partitions mounted to each /home/user. Then I edit fstab with the UUIDs to mount at boot. I rebooted into emergency mode =0

I edit fstab again, changed the type to auto and gave the options to remount on errors, reboot, and it worked.

My big issue now is that things still aren't quite lining up right. Like somehow their home folders ended up in my home(~/) folder, theirs don't have the desktop, documents, and so on directories in them, so I'm not sure what I did wrong. It's honestly kind of a blur at this point. Been a while since I BASHed it out and I probably copied something wrong or ing the wrong order. I'd like my wife and I to basically share access to all the files like photos, videos and music, but also have her own space. And the kid to have his own space, but all these spaces, especially the kid's, walled off from each other, somewhat for security by isolation and so one could potentially be rescued by the other. Ar least that was my idea behind it.

I'M a total AMATUER at Linux in general bbn so anyone who can help and knows what info might help, I can run whatever checks on the terminal, I just don't know where to start looking.

Comment: Open a terminal and type the command `cat /etc/fstab`. Then copy the output of that command using the mouse, and [paste it directly in your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1457923/edit). Then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: What filesystems are on those partitions Windows(*NTFS*) or Ubuntu(*EXT4*)?

Comment: Your wife and son has tried logging in?  The Desktop, Documents, etc. directories are created after they log in the first time.  If your son doesn't have `sudo` access, then che should be "walled off" in his home directory.  As previously suggested, you should post your `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1457923/edit) and add all the information asked for by all the commenters.